# Load balancing 2x IIS Webservers, across subnets

Tags: iis, rewrite, failover, subnet

Morning chaps,

Currently we've got one virtual webserver, and if it goes down, nobody can login or access our Intranet.

To resolve this I've installed two test servers (2012 R2), one on our first site (x.x.1.x) and one on our second site (x.x.2.x).

I'd like to put in a solution whereby everything is pointed to an address of webcluster, which is shared between site1-webserver, and site2-webserver.

Without purchasing hardware, I'm looking for the best way forward. NLB doesn't seem to quite fit the bill (due to multiple subnets), and while URL re-write in IIS does seem to fit the bill, it does look as if it'd require a third server in the mix, which would become a single point of failure.

I was looking at IIS hosted on Azure, but I don't think Azure plays too nicely with AD integration just yet (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Suggestions on the best way forward?

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: do you need the web servers in both sites because of slow/high latency wan links? Or could you set the web servers in just one of the sites?

Comment: We had a power cut in one site for the day and it took down the other sites ability to login, so a completely redundant solution is what I'm after if possible.

Comment: Just to add, we have a private 100mbit site-to-site link, so latency is minimal.

Comment: you'll then need some kind of virtual ip spanning both data centers, so you'll need to get in touch with your network admins. Or you can put your intranet on the internet, properly secured it should be ok. You can run a federated AD in Azure as well, plenty of people do that

Comment: Hi Giles, I am interested in your Azure comment. can I have some more details please? Azure does work with Active Directory really well both on premise AD and Azure AD. Setting up the VMs in azure would be an extra expense but it would provide the solution you need.

Comment: Also are you using virtualization on premise? are your webserver VMs running on HyperV or are they running on physical servers.

Comment: Hi Michael. So what we have is 2x servers, both running Hyper-V, with an IIS server on each.

Comment: As for Azure, I looked into Azure for SQL, and found I couldn't sync local users to it. I assumed the same for IIS. If this isn't the case, I'm most interested?

Comment: Further clarification, we currently run Office 365 using Azure AD Connect, so we are currently syncing users to the cloud.

Comment: Hi, it may not solve you problem but in Azure there is a new feature called Azure Domain Services. it is in public preview at the minute. once configured you can join Azure IAAS VMs to Azure Domain services. Azure domain Service has access to all you Azure AD connect synced accounts so your synced users can authenticate against Azure domain Services and the accounts are available to login to the IAAS vms. you can even create a GPO and apply it to the IAAS VMs. two IAAS VMs running IIS sat behind the internal or external load balancer, with your account being able to authenticate against them.

Comment: Michael, I think this might indeed be the easier option. I've signed up for an account and I'll test it out.

Answer (score 0):

in Azure there is a new feature called Azure Domain Services. it is in public preview at the minute. once configured you can join Azure IAAS VMs to Azure Domain services. Azure domain Service has access to all you Azure AD connect synced accounts so your synced users can authenticate against Azure domain Services and the accounts are available to login to the IAAS vms. you can even create a GPO and apply it to the IAAS VMs. two IAAS VMs running IIS sat behind the internal or external load balancer, with your account being able to authenticate against them

Comment: I'd upvote this as the answer, but I don't have the reputation yet, thanks Michael!